# Get height / width of uiview set using contraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How can I retrieve the calculated height/width of a `UIView` is the height and/or width was let using a `NSConstraint` ?

To explain differently:
I would like to retrieve the `CGFloat` value of a `UIView's` "width" or "height" after the element has been laid out using autolayout and constraints.

Comment: Do you want to get the height/width of view after it gets updated via autolayout and constraints ?

Comment: Please recheck your question description. Seems like some grammatical issue.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar yes, exactly.

Comment: @Mr.UB thanks! Edited it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular point when you are certain your views were completely laid out by the layout system. But there are some methods that are being called after each layout cycle.

So if your `textField` is a custom class or part of a custom `UIView`, like a `UITableViewCell`, this method would be `layoutSubviews`. In this care you can get the size using the following code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textWidth = textField.frame.width
    textHeight = textField.frame.height
}
```

This code will give you the right values every time something changes in they layout(like orientation change or some other elements changed their frames or constraints).

If you dont have a custom view, but you are using the textField straight in a `UIViewController`, the method is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. This gets called after the viewController completes layout of the entire view hierarchy.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textWidth = textField.frame.width
    textHeight = textField.frame.height
}
```

Let me know if I can help you further or if you have more questions. Hope this helps with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get height & widht depending on content of the view

```
let adjustedWidth = anyView.intrinsicContentSize.width 
let adjustedHeight = anyView.intrinsicContentSize.height
```

Comment: Ah brilliant. Giving it a shot.

Comment: hmmm. Not sure if it works perfectly. I set the width and height to be 200 and 100 of a UITextField. Although intrinsicContentSize returned (112, 21).

Comment: This doesn't provide the actual width/height just the *intrinsic* width and height, ie. the size the view would be if it could choose.

Answer (score 0):

Provided a view is constrained, you can get its “fitting” size using:

```
let size = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

If you get invalid values then your view is not constrained or you are calling it before its parent has been laid-out.